# how to build a find query from client side to search mongo db?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to build a search page, I want to build a "find query" by the criterions the client filing. 
How can I do this?

I have tried to build a query string in js but it doesn't work, then I tried to  build a dictionary of the criterions, criterionName : criterionValue also not worked

```js
var query = req.body.query;
        console.log("Connected To Server");
        var mydb =  db.db('');
        var docToSearch = mydb.collection('docs');
        docToSearch.find(query)
                    .toArray(function(err,result){
                        return res.send(result);
                    });
      }
```

```js
function GetSearchQuery(criterionsToSearch){
    let query = [];
    criterionsToSearch.forEach(function(criterion, index){
        let input = $("input[data-criterion='" + criterion + "']");
        let select = $("select[data-criterion='" + criterion + "']");
        let criterionName,criterionValue;
        if(input.length)  {criterionName =  $(input).attr("name"); criterionValue = $(input).val(); }
        if(select.length) {criterionName =  $(select).attr("name"); criterionValue = $(select).val();}
        query.Add({criterionName:criterionValue});
    });
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the actual queries that you're trying & the format of the data in your mongo collection?

Comment: Are you really willing to trust blindly a query passed by the client and execute it, eyes closed, on your database?
Let the client pass parameters, validate them, and build the query on the server side...

Comment: You right about the client. how I build a query on the server side?
my problem is that I don't know how many parameters I gonna get, there are some that are a must but some are not